# Is there a way to disable zooming in svg-edit?

Tags: svg-edit

I know I can just hide the zoom buttons, but users would still be able to zoom with their mouse wheel. Maybe something along the lines of:

svgEditor.setConfig({
    enableZoom: false
});

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to disable zoom and from what I can tell no easy way to override it with an extension so the quickest way to accomplish what you're trying to do is probably find where the zoom function is defined and return early.

So open {svg-edit folder}\svg-editor.js and find

```
var zoomChanged = svgCanvas.zoomChanged = function
```

It's on line #794 for me. After the curly brace just add "return false" and then users won't be able to zoom at all.

Also, what do you mean "users would still be able to zoom with their mouse wheel"? Mouse wheel just scrolls vertically as with any other webpage for me.

Comment: Hi GoTeamScotch, thank you for your response. Unfortunately my company has moved away from using this application since I asked the question back in November. Therefore, I can't validate if your answer is correct or not. Hopefully someone else finds it useful!